# How can i create an mp4 out of an image sequance

Tags: python, image, image-processing, video-processing

I'm trying to create a program that I can give it a source folder (that contains for example jpeg images) and a destination folder (that the mp4 will go to) I want to be able to set a specific delay between every image so for example, the first image would be shown for 1 second and the second for 4 seconds

I don't want to use FFmpeg I want to edit the image in the process so I'd rather have a for loop or something like that so I can edit every image

I have tried using FFmpeg and moviepy I couldn't figure out how to do it
any ideas?

Another thing if someone knows how i can take an image that is not the right size and kinda duplictae it to the backround of the image make it bigger and blur it? So the image has its original size with a blurry backround that is its duplicate

Comment: *"I don't want to use FFmpeg"* Why not?

Comment: I want to be able to customize the code more with ffmpeg its harder

Comment: Could you give an example of what process you want to do with the images?

Comment: add a blurry backround (the last 3 lines in my question..) maybe convert to gray scale etc..

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it manually, and assuming you have bunch of `.jpeg` files and you know the duration of each file, then using `opencv.VideoWriter()`, you can repeat the frames based one the frame rate and then write all frames into the output.

```py
import cv2

# Each video has a frame per second which is number of frames in every second
frame_per_second = 15

files_and_duration = [
    ('file1.jpeg', 4),
    ('file2.jpeg', 1),
    ('file3.jpeg', 2)
]

w, h = None, None
for file, duration in files_and_duration:
    frame = cv2.imread(file)

    if w is None:
        # Setting up the video writer
        h, w, _ = frame.shape
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v')
        writer = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', fourcc, frame_per_second, (w, h))

    # Repating the frame to fill the duration
    for repeat in range(duration * frame_per_second):
        writer.write(frame)

writer.release()
```

Comment: Just wondering if there's any real necessity to accumulate all the frames in memory in a list... what if it's a long video, or large frames or high frame rate? Wouldn't it be better to write them one at a time? For example, frames for a 1080p 24fps video accumulate at around 150MB per second of video...

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks for pointing that out, you're right, I changed the code so that it writes each frame to the disk after loading it

Comment: Cool - I think/hope that's a better approach. You already have my vote

Comment: Thanks ill try that

Comment: It worked.. I think because when I open the mp4 it shows me: This file isn't playable. That might be because the file type is unsupported, the file extension is incorrect, or the file is corrupt.

Comment: @KingOfTNT10 Yes, I found the problem. I forgot to release/close the `writer` after writing the last frame. I edit the code ( the last line` and should be fine now

Comment: it's still saying This file isn't playable. That might be because the file type is unsupported, the file extension is incorrect, or the file is corrupt.

Comment: @KingOfTNT10 I was testing it on square photos and then I realized that the `frame.shape()` is returning the width and height in different order. Can you try now? I edited the code

Comment: It worked thank you so much!! btw do you maybe know how can i do the thing i described on the last 3 lines in my question?